# Simplifying inverses of polynomials to real functions

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, inverse-function

For example, I have a polynomial:
$$f(x)=-\frac{1}{4}x^3 + \frac{3}{4}x + \frac{1}{2}$$
And one of its inverses is:
$$f^{-1}(x) = \frac{-(1 + i \sqrt{3}) (-2 x + 2 \sqrt{(x - 1) x} + 1)^{2/3} + i \sqrt{3} - 1}{2 \sqrt[3]{-2 x + 2 \sqrt{(x - 1) x} + 1}}$$
In the real domain 0<x<1 it has a real codomain -1<y<1.
Is it possible to simplify inverses of polynomials to "real functions"? By which I mean I want the new function to have same values in a given domain as the original one and I want to be able to find any value in that domain by doing real number calculations only.

Comment: @user2661923 Thanks for replying. There are 3 solutions to the example polynomial (see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y%3D-x%5E3%2F4+%2B+%283+x%29%2F4+%2B+1%2F2) and the first one doesn't use complex numbers. However, that solution is only for y>1 as far as I understand.

Comment: If you plot the 3 solutions in Wolfram (after replacing x and y), you'll see that the first one is real for x<1 and 1<y (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28-2+x+%2B+2+sqrt%28%28x+-+1%29+x%29+%2B+1%29%5E%281%2F3%29+%2B+1%2F%28-2+x+%2B+2+sqrt%28%28x+-+1%29+x%29+%2B+1%29%5E%281%2F3%29), the second one is real for 0<x and y<-1 (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28i+%28sqrt%283%29+%2B+i%29+%28-2+x+%2B+2+sqrt%28%28x+-+1%29+x%29+%2B+1%29%5E%282%2F3%29+-+i+sqrt%283%29+-+1%29%2F%282+%28-2+x+%2B+2+sqrt%28%28x+-+1%29+x%29+%2B+1%29%5E%281%2F3%29%29) and the third one 0<x<1 and -1<y<1

Comment: I see what's going on now.  I think that the first step is to identify the root $= r(x)$ that you want the inverse of, be very explicit about limiting the domain of $r(x)$ so that the **range** of $r(x)$ is limited to real values, and then re-write $r(x)$ **removing all imaginary parts**, expressing it as if you know that given the restricted domain, the range was going to be limited to $\mathbb{R}.$  **Then**, that is the expression that you want to calculate the inverse of.  It seems to me that this **will** be possible (but I am just **guessing**).

Comment: @user2661923 (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28-%281+%2B+i+sqrt%283%29%29+%28-2+x+%2B+2+sqrt%28%28x+-+1%29+x%29+%2B+1%29%5E%282%2F3%29+%2B+i+sqrt%283%29+-+1%29%2F%282+%28-2+x+%2B+2+sqrt%28%28x+-+1%29+x%29+%2B+1%29%5E%281%2F3%29%29). These functions are already real-valued within their domains and I am not even considering complex domains. In other words, x is always real and y is real as long as x is in bounds. It is indeed fascinating that functions that have "i" in them can be real-valued at all.

Comment: Still, pick out the root that you want the inverse of, and re-express it to remove any $i$ term, if possible.

Comment: @user2661923 Thanks, I'll try reading about it. I think it's not possible in general to re-express removing complex numbers but I'm just guessing

Comment: It should be.  All you have to do is convert $i$ to $\sqrt{-1}.$  Based on the Wolfram Alpha results, by substituting this factor for $i$, it **must** result in a real valued expression for the restricted domain.  Therefore, it **has** to be possible to re-express the root with $i$ removed.

Comment: Now, I'm confused again.  In your comment that begins "If you plot the 3 solutions in Wolfram...", you linked to Wolfram Alpha.  I saw what was being plotted.  The function I saw contains **no** $i$ term.  That is exactly what I was referring to.  What you want is to **edit your query to show that root, just as it appeared in Wolfram Alpha**, and ask how to compute the inverse of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the cubic equation
$$-\frac{1}{4}x^3 + \frac{3}{4}x + \frac{1}{2}-y=0$$

I shall follow the steps given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation).

The discriminant
$$\Delta=-\frac{27}{16} (y-1) y$$ is negative for any $y <0$ and $y >1$. So, one real root except for $0 \leq y \leq 1$.

On the other side, we have $p=-3$ and $q=4 y-2$

$$y<0 \implies x=2 \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}(1-2 y)\right)$$
$$y>1 \implies x=-2 \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}(2 y-1)\right)$$

Now, the problem is that, for $0 \leq x \leq 1$, $\frac 12 \leq y \leq 1$. So $\Delta >0$ and three real roots. Using the trigonomatric method
$$x_k=2 \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  k}{3}-\frac{1}{3} \cos ^{-1}(1-2 y)\right)\qquad \text{with} \qquad k=0,1,2$$